# How can I best pattern match in Result::map

Tags: rust

I know I can pattern match like this in rust

```rust
some_result.map(|some_number| {
    match some_number {
        1 => HttpResponse::NoContent().finish(),
        _ => HttpResponse::NotFound().finish(),
    }
})
```

but in Scala I can do like this

```scala
some_option.map {
    case 1 => ???
    case _ => ???
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the repetition of the variable `some_number` in the rust code above?

**EDIT:**

I found out i could do it this way, but i still think the original question answered my question best.

```rust
    Ok(match result {
        Ok(1) => HttpResponse::NoContent(),
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::NotFound(),
        Err(_) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError()
    }.finish())
```

its all about the context and in this case i didnt include much of it ...

**EDIT #2:**

Changed to another answer. I really like inverting the problem. And if else is not idiomatic rust afaik.

Comment: `some_number` => `n` or consider use a function.

Comment: I have thoroughly explained why I think my answer is more idiomatic, and an alternative if you also want to handle the error case. Please, check it out and give me your feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we're just bike-shedding style, you could avoid introducing `some_number` entirely by matching on the whole result:

```
match some_result {
    Ok(1) => Ok(HttpResponse::NoContent().finish()),
    Ok(_) => Ok(HttpResponse::NotFound().finish()),
    Err(e) => Err(e)
};
```

But this just trades `some_number` for some `Ok`s and `Err`s. I would generally prefer  the original style, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Definitely more slender code. Come to think of it i might just remove my map and map_err with this code. I just had this long chain and focused on a map in that chain. But i can equally as well rewrite the shit 

Comment: thanks! see my edit in the original post :)

Comment: @JarlAndréHübenthal yeah, if the error is left untouched I would prefer `.map()` like your original, but if the `Ok` and `Err` are going to be transformed into the same type, I'd definitely prefer the bigger `match`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way that I know of to avoid the repetition, however I think it might be more idiomatic to simply write

```rust
some_result.map(
  |some_number|
  if some_number == 1 {
    HttpResponse::NoContent().finish()
  } else {
    HttpResponse::NotFound().finish()
  }
)
```

since there is no need for a `match` in such a simple situation.

**EDIT**: Why is an `if` statement more idiomatic than a `match` on in this situation?

The general idea is that `match` is more powerful than `if` (every `if` statement could be replaced by a `match` statement), therefore `if` is more specific, and thus should be used when possible (without `matches!`). The only exception is the `switch/case` use-case, which could be expressed as an `if` statement but a `match` one should be used.

But this is more of a guideline than an argument, so let's break down the reason why `if` is more idiomatic.

You start with something like

```rust
match some_number {
  1 => { ... }
  _ => { ... }
}
```

In the situation of

```rust
match x {
  Pattern => { ... }
  _ => { ... }
}
```

`if let` is more idiomatic. Since we're in this situation, we can rewrite

```rust
if let 1 = some_number { ... } else { ... }
```

However, in our case, we are matching a single literal, so it is more idiomatic to simply transform the `if let` into

```rust
if some_number == 1 { ... } else { ... }
```

The only exception is when you are planning to add more branching to the `match` statement, like

```rust
match some_number {
  1 => { ... }
  2 => { ... }
  _ => { ... }
}
```

in which case it would make sense to keep it like that.

Keep in mind that being idiomatic also means being able to convey by the way you code your intention so that your programming becomes clear.

**Note**: Why is this more idiomatic than than simply matching the whole result?

Most of the time, being idiomatic is a synonym of being concise. If you are being verbose, it's a good hint you're not being idiomatic. However, it'is not always true, and this is a good example of being idiomatic meaning being more verbose.

When you are matching a result, you are expressing that you want to handle both the error and the ok case. When you are mapping, you are instead expressing that you are only interested in the ok case.

Most of the time, people don't want to handle manually the error case, and just add a `?`. However, when they don't, most of the time they want to handle the error case. Finally, they might want not to handle the error, but also not to get rid of it right away.

These three choices are increasingly verbose to implement due to the frequency of usage. This means that you should not aim for the one that is less verbose, but instead for the solution that matches your intention, so that when one reads your code, it's easier to grasp your intention just by your choice structure of implementation.

In your original question, you seemed not to care about the error case, and also you didn't seem to want to get rid of it with `?`, which is why I think that having an `if` statement inside a `map` is more idiomatic, in the sense that it is more clear and communicates better what you want to achieve. Indeed, I didn't even think about the error case, which is, IMO, what idiomatic means (ie. the capacity of adapting the way one thinks to ease the comprehension of code by writing it in the most expressive way, for a given language).

Finally, I would point out the most idiomatic choice for handling an error, that you didn't seem to take into account, and I wonder why.

```rust
if some_result? == 1 {
  HttpResponse::NoContent().finish()
} else {
  HttpResponse::NotFound().finish()
}
```

Where you have implemented an appropriate conversion from the eventual error type to the return type.

Comment: It makes sense, both methods. However, if some_number was an option and if i needed to guard the value inside the option i would most likely need match anyway. But thats another scenario ;)

Comment: Not quite, you could also do it with the `matches!` macro, which is exactly meant for this kind of situation.

Comment: Yeah .. im coming from scala though .. and macros in scala and rust makes me shiver. however .. macros in rust is more normal than macros in scala. I see its used everywhere, literally.

Comment: No, you didn't understood what I meant. For your question, macros are not useful. If `some_number` was an option, then you could use the `macthes!` macro alongside with my solution. It would look like `if matches!(some_number, Some(1)) { ... }`. ;)

Comment: but seriously, is it in rust std library, the `matches!` macro? If it is, then thats another story as well

Comment: Yes, it is :D https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html

Comment: ah okey i see. So for simple numbers i dont need any macro sillyness. But for more complex structs i could use the `matches!` macro.. ill check it out

Comment: You should definitively! Rust is a very young language, and macros (among other purposes) cover some syntax lacks compared with other languages. Most likely, in the future you'll have a more idiomatic solution to your problem, but for the time being knowing the right macro at the right time can save a lot of boilerplate, and it doesn't require understanding how macro work (which is a bit harder than using them).

Comment: How is this more idiomatic? Could you please improve this answer by giving objective arguments on how your change improves the code compared to the original question?

Comment: @SirDarius When I answered, I didn't see the edit in the question, so I edited both to answer you and to answer the edit. If there are shadowy parts in my reasoning, please point them out.